# state appears not to be updating, possible async issue?

Tags: reactjs

I currently have the following code:

```
.then(keyUid => {
  let updatedFamily = {...family, [keyUid]: [firstHousehold, lastHousehold, householdDropdown]};
  console.log(updatedFamily);
  this.props.firebase.db.ref('organization/' + currentOrganization + '/members/' + keyUid ).set(
    {
        first: firstHousehold,
        last: lastHousehold,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        address: address,
        address2: address2,
        city: city,
        zip: zip,
        headOfHousehold: headOfHousehold,
      })
      this.setState({ family: updatedFamily }, () => console.log(family));

      return keyUid;
})
```

The above code is part of a larger code block and here I'm only including the relative .then when I `console.log (updatedFamily);` I have two items in an array.  I then make a call to update a firebase reference.  After I run a this.setState where I'm setting family (this.state.family is set 
to family above in the code block not shown).  WhenI console.log(family) after the this.setState I only get back one item.

Not sure why this is happening, is it that my `return keyUid` executes BEFORE `this.setState`?  Or can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Show back updated state by using `this.state.family` but not just `family`.

`family` is old one.

```
this.setState({ family: updatedFamily }, () => console.log(this.state.family));
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async yes, so it will be executed after the `return` statement.

But the reason why you don't see your updated `family`state property is because you need to log `this.state.family` after `setState`.

Comment: @Antonio I guess he is right, but he said it in a way so you have to read twice to understand. He probably meant to log `this.state.family` after `setState` instead of log `family` which the OP does.

Comment: Yes, I edited while you where answering. Your comment @Antonio was a good point to clarify that the `setState` callback is executed after state has been updated.